# How does "use strict" modify the rules for "this" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, this, use-strict

I'm trying to understand what rule for "this" that "use strict"; modifies in the below case.

After reading (http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/) my best guess is that since the functon isStrictModeOn() is not "attached" to anything, this refers to null. Which is suppose to be a more sensible alternative to Javascript just attaching the this to the global object. Is that the correct interpretation of the change that "use strict" is making in this case?

http://www.novogeek.com/post/ECMAScript-5-Strict-mode-support-in-browsers-What-does-this-mean.aspx

```
function isStrictMode(){
    return !this;
} 
//returns false, since 'this' refers to global object and '!this' becomes false

function isStrictModeOn(){   
    "use strict";
    return !this;
} 
//returns true, since in strict mode, the keyword 'this' does not refer to global object, unlike traditional JS. So here,'this' is null and '!this' becomes true.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's almost correct.  In strict mode, when a function is invoked without a receiver then `this` is `undefined` (not `null`).  A better version of that function would be:

```
function isStrict() {
  "use strict";
  return (typeof this) === 'undefined';
}
```

An inherent problem with functions like that is that "strictness" is determined lexically, like scope, so it's static.  A tester function that includes its own `"use strict";` isn't very useful; it really only tells you whether the JavaScript runtime understands strict mode. One without its own `"use strict";` tells you whether the lexical context in which it's defined is in strict mode.  That is:

```
function isStrict() {
  function test() {
    return (typeof this) === 'undefined';
  }
  return test();
}
```

will tell you, when called, whether a `"use strict";` was in effect for the scope at which the function is defined.  I guess that could be useful.  However, if a reference to that function "leaks" into some other context whose "strictness" differs, it's going to continue to report on its static strictness at the point of its definition.

Personally, I would opt for simply ensuring that my code is definitely in strict mode by invoking `"use strict";` at the outermost layer possible.  That way there's really no need to check for it.

Comment: @dandavis I don't know; just habit. They're unnecessary but they won't hurt anything. (I assume you mean the parens around the `typeof` subexpression.)

Comment: cool, good to know, but how can you tell about it being active globally?

Comment: @dandavis well the second one I posted will *kind-of* do that; the problem is knowing what "globally" means in JavaScript.